# error with threadprivate in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I ran an example of **OpenMP** program to test the function of `threadprivate`, but the result is unexpected and nondetermined. (The program is run on ubuntu 14.04 in VMware.)

the source code is shown in the following:

```
int counter = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate (counter)
int inc_counter()
{
  counter++;
  return counter;
}

void main()
{
  #pragma omp parallel sections copyin(counter)
  {
    #pragma omp section
    {
      int count1;
      for(int iter = 0; iter < 100; ++iter)
        count1 = inc_counter();
      printf("count1 = %1d\n", count1);
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
      int count2;
      for(int iter=0; iter<200; iter++)
        count2 = inc_counter();
      printf("count2 = %d\n", count2);
    }
  }
  printf("counter = %d\n", counter);
}
```

> The output of the program is:

[image]

The correct output should be:

```
count1 = 100
count2 = 200
counter = 0/100/200?
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

`threadprivate` differs from `private` in the sense that it doesn't have to allocate local variable for each thread, the variable only have to be unique for each thread. One of you threads (master) uses global counter defined in `int counter = 0;`. Therefore this thread changes this value to 100, 200 or leave it unchanged (0), depending on what section this single thread started to execute.

As you highlighted it seems weird for you why program is giving next results for (count1,count2,counter): (100,300,300) and (100,300,0).

1. (100,300,300)

   Master thread executes both sections. You can check it by launching your code with single thread: `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./ex_omp`
2. (100,300,0)

   Some thread execute both sections while master is idle. You can check it by introducing section (alongside your two):

   ```
   #pragma omp section
   {   
     sleep(1); // #include <unistd.h>
     printf("hope it is 0 (master) -> %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
   }
   ```

   If you have 2 threads and master starts to execute this section then another thread with high probability execute your two other sections and you will get (100,300,0) as expected. Launch for example as `OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./ex_omp`.

If it still seems wrong that `count2 = 300` you should notice that `count` is not private for section, it is private for a thread, while this thread can execute both sections.

Comment: Thanks. But how can you explain the output `count1=100, count2=300, counter=0` ?

Comment: @BailinLu I've added an explanation, you can check it now.